# "where lay a gulf all the blacker for its glittering walls" - "all the..for" meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Translating one of Lovecraft's stories, I got stuck because of the following sentence:

> where lay a gulf all the blacker for its glittering walls.

Particularly, it is the "all the" combined with "for" part.

My possible interpretations:

1. ..even more black than the (already) very bright/great glitter of its walls
2. ...blacker despite the glitter of the walls (as if the blackness set off the contrast)

Comment: It's a little bit "stylised", but you'll often hear people say after they've taken some medicine, followed some exercise regime, or similar, that they ***feel all the better** [for having done so.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22feel+all+the+better+for%22) Many people will have first encountered the format from *Little Red Riding Hood's* "What big teeth you have, Grandma!". To which The Big Bad Wolf (disguised as Grandma) replies ***All the better to eat you with**!*

Answer (score 1):

For reference you might want to read the definition of "[all the more so](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28all%29%20the%20more%20so)". You can say something has a particular quality and then follow that by adding that the quality is "all the more so" *for* a particular reason. Or, as in your example, you can say it in one statement by using a *comparative adjective* (eg one ending 'er', such as tinier, smoother, faster etc) and say "all the [smooth]er for...".

In your example, 'all the blacker' means that the aforementioned 'gulf' was **more black *because*** it has glittering walls. You would take from this that, even without the glittering walls it would be black, but *more so* because of them. What that means in real terms is either open to interpretation or requires the wider context of the book.

A comparable example using the same syntax would be "the cake was all the sweeter for having extra sugar in it".

Comment: That sentence sounds like something they would ask in a GRE question. "All the more so" is a quite common phrase, but "all the blacker" sounds so odd. Is this like very old English or something?

Comment: @AIQ "All the blacker" isn't a known idiom... it's just making use of a recognisable turn of phrase. You can use pretty much any comparative adjective - "the burger was all the tastier for the delicious sauce".

Comment: Worth adding that “All the X for Y” is most often used when Y is in some way *contrasting” with X.  So its use in your cake example seems slightly un-idiomatic to me — I’d expect it more in something like “the cake was all the sweeter for the tart gooseberry sauce with it”.